# Concatenate and remove carriage return in Shell Script

Tags: shell, http, curl

In shell script I am doing the following:

```
locationUrl=$(grep -r "Location:" output.txt)
fullUrl="http://test.com/temp/${locationUrl##*/}"
tempUrl="$fullUrl/tests"
echo $tempUrl
```

My expected output is

```
http://test.com/temp/226/tests
```

But I get this:

```
/tests/test.com/temp/226
```

The **output.txt** looks like bellow:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://test.dev:8080/webservice/temp/226
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that output.txt has carrige returns in it.  Piping the output through `tr -d '\r'` removes these.  I suggest you try:

```
locationUrl=$(grep -r "Location:" output.txt | tr -d '\r')
entries="entries"
fullUrl="http://test.com/temp/${locationUrl##*/}"
tempUrl="$fullUrl/tests"
echo $tempUrl
```

Your original code is probably outputting `http://test.com/temp/226^M/tests` with the ^M causing your terminal to start rewriting the current line.  You can check this by piping the output through `less`:

```
$ sh test.s | less
http://test.com/temp/226^M/tests
```